# Overlay becomes unclickable after widget rebuild

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter_typeahead field, and I use riverpod. When I add this line to my widget build method, it triggers a rebuild:

```
final factory = ref.watch(formFactoryProvider);
```

My flutter_typeahead `onSuggestionSelected` stops firing when I click on a suggestion. The suggestion list is an `OverlayEntry` in the package.

If I remove that above line, the overlay registers the click event every time.

Here is my flutter_typeahead usage; it is quite buried in abstraction, so I'm just showing the abstraction:

```
  @override
  Widget nameTextField(
    SizingInformation sizingInfo,
    FormModel<dynamic> formModel,
    DetailsVm vm,
  ) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) => VpVgnItmsAutocompleteField.groceryItms(
        key: ref.watch(fieldKeyProvider(DetailsForm.nameControlName)),
        delayShowError: DELAY_SHOW_ERROR_DURATION,
        formControlName: DetailsForm.nameControlName,
        form: formModel.form,
        focusNode: focusNodeName,
        sizingInfo: sizingInfo,
        nextField: DetailsForm.companyNameControlName,
        onSelected: (TVgnItmSuggestion vi) async =>
            await vm.onVgnItmSelected(entity: vi.value),
        labelText: 'Grocery Item Name',
        hintText: 'Ex: Vegan Hunny Coconut Nectar...'.ellipses(),
        validationMessages: {
          'required': (error) => 'Please enter the name of the Grocery Item'
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Does anyone know why a rebuild would stop an overlay from registering click events?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to fix it when I use a `UniqueKey()` for the key instead of the key in the question. So it is something to do with the widget lifecycle, I think a `UniqueKey` refreshes it to a cleaner state. It used to always work only on the first time, so I wanted to make all future times behave as the first time, which it seems like `UniqueKey` does. I would be happy for someone to add more technical comments about the `UniqueKey` widget and what effects it has.